# Firebase Storage bucket not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I wanted to try the latest Firebase now has Storage but I got this error "Can't connect to server. Try again in a few minutes.
RETRY
"  when I go to the new console, Storage, Files.

How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a known bug where if you are logged in to more than one google account, the account switching isn't done properly and it messes things up. I filed a support ticket and got back the following reply:

> Thanks for reaching out and reporting this.
>
> We are working on a fix for this. We currently don't have an ETA when
>   a fix will be released.
>
> Current work around would be just to have one Google account logged
>   in.
>
> Cheers, XYZ

Comment: Wow. This so true. Thanks for sharing Chris.

Comment: is it solved ? tried posting about this issue to https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ also.

Comment: I don't know @arvindwill. I'm still using a seperate browser for this

Comment: Thanks @Chris , even that one account method is not working here.

Comment: yes @Chris incognito,different browser and differnt system browser also

Comment: @andrescabana86 I am not sure. I created a new project today via firebase console, and the bucket url was added. however, the project I imported doesn't have the bucket url.

Comment: i solve my problem erasing all projects, loggin out all my accounts, cleaning cloud google projects and starting a new project.

Answer (score 7):

The storage panel uses some APIs which are enabled when you create your project, but there can be a delay in the set up completing. Try returning to the console after some time, and refreshing the storage panel, and you should be good to go!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that several times even until now but it's the same problem. I forgot to mention but my firebase is from the previous console and I upgraded it to the latest one. But that shouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure what else I've missed.

Comment: Possibly some APIs didn't get enabled. Can you go to https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apis/enabled and check Google Cloud Storage API and App Engine Admin API  are enabled (and enable them if not, and try the storage panel again). If no progress, could you file a ticket with the details of your project: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ - thanks!

Comment: Cloud Storage API, Cloud Storage JSON API and App Engine Admin API are already enabled. I have never used Google Cloud Platform before. I see that there's a "sign up" for GCP. Should I need to have a GCP account and billing enabled before I can use Storage? I thought by migrating and updating my Firebase, the process would be seamless and I could use it right away. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Yeah, it should be - you've hit a bug unfortunately, sorry about that. You don't need to sign up for billing to try it out. Can you see if there is a Cloud Storage bucket already existing: https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser?project=_ for your project?

Comment: It doesn't look like it has. In "Explore other services" section, there's "create a cloud storage bucket". When I hit that, it asks me to sign up.

Comment: Hmm, thats what visiting the storage tab should configure - refreshing that should create the bucket. If you go to the AppEngine page in the cloud console, do you get any more errors (the free bucket is associated with an appengine instance)?

Comment: I don't see any bucket even after waiting hours after refreshing the storage tab. AppEngine only has options for me to Try AppEngine Now or visit the docs.

Comment: No further suggestions sorry - can you file a bug with the troubleshooting link above and include your project ID?

Comment: OK I filed it. Thanks Ian

Comment: as @Dumpee explained facing the same problem.  only difference in appengine side which displays "This operation is not possible because no App Engine application was found for this project." . Also checked Cloud Storage API and AppEngine Admin API both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Ian Barber in 2016 seems to still be valid in 2022.

My experience for two projects now has been "Open the Firebase storage panel, refresh the page, and the error will no longer occur"

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."
  }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334122/11125318

Comment: You really think Firebase and Google still have the same bug after 7 years ? You know that you're showing different error then in a question ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issues previously. Try accessing it in incognito mode. This was actually the solution from Firebase support and it worked. They are still trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: incognito didnt helped in my case.