# Firebase Storage Permission unknown error with React Native Image Upload

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

Actual demo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYGi71am_tU

Firebase Storage RULES:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.*');
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

My blob image:

```
Blob {
   "_data": Object {
     "blobId": "c526586a-0481-48ce-a77b-cc589052a443",
     "lastModified": 0,
     "name": "bbf91dba-8597-43d9-82b7-7a81887c3e5c.jpg",
     "offset": 0,
     "size": 32653,
     "type": "image/jpeg",
   },
}
```

Firebase Storage error :

```
FirebaseStorageError {
   "code_": "storage/unknown",
   "column": 31,
   "line": 17422,
   "message_": "Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response.",
   "name_": "FirebaseError",
   "serverResponse_": "{
   \"error\": {
     \"code\": 400,
     \"message\": \"Permission denied. Could not access bucket crna-app-01.appspot.com. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources.\"
   }
 }",
   "sourceURL": "http://10.1.0.6:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2Fajinkyaborade%2Fprojects%2Fnative-apps%2Fmy-react-redux%2Fnode_modules%2Fexpo%2Ftools%2FhashAssetFiles",
 }
```

And this is the actual function from my Expo RN app file

```
async function uploadImageAsync(uri, uid, firebase) {

  const response = await fetch(uri);

  const blob = await response.blob();

  const ref = firebase
    .storage()
    .ref('users/' + uid)
    .child(uuid.v4());

  const snapshot = await ref.put(blob); // actual Firebase error comes here
  return snapshot.downloadURL;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: This is the Firebase Storage error message from above: "Permission denied. Could not access bucket crna-app-01.appspot.com. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."  Is this message meaningful or actionable for you?

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for reply. I had previously uploaded files using same method, but suddenly it stopped working. Yes Storage is enabled. I have even added `RULES`

Comment: Please help us understand "suddenly".  Please edit the question to include what was working before that is no longer working *with no changes to what you're posted".

Comment: updated question @DougStevenson

Comment: I tried with RULES `allow write;` still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with Firebase storage admin.

- Go to Console > Storage https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=[PROJECT-NAME]
- Select your bucket then click show info panel.
  [image]

-- add `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` as Storage **ADMIN**
done

Comment: many thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292353/firebase-storage-security-rules-400-error-issue-permission-denied-could-not-ac