# Firebase Cloud Storage Permission denied issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, angularfire2

I started out with an issue simply displaying storage contents. The error message was the same Code 400 "Permission denied. Could not access bucket bucket. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."

But the changes I made based on [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292353/firebase-storage-security-rules-400-error-issue-permission-denied-could-not-ac) made the issue worse, now my upload form is giving the same error now and blocks file uploads, even after rolling back all the changes. I tried creating a brand new project on Firebase, but that has the same error. 
I also tried to set my bucket permissions to

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

since I thought that it could be a rights issue, but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you also post the code you use to upload to GCS?

Comment: Sure, I'll recreate the app on stackblitz and link it in once I have it up and running.

Comment: Do not link your code. Put your code in your question. Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have you checked if your project falls in any of the known issues for storage in Firebase? https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#storage-buckets

Comment: Actually I was working on reproducing the issue in a stackblitz and I noticed the error "Permission denied. could not access bucket **bucket**." Bucket of course is not my storage bucket. So now I think the issue is with the code. I'm going to go over the service again and if I can't get it to work I'll post a stackblitz. This is frustrating because I thought I undid all of the troubleshooting changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what I was trying to do when I added this bit of code, but I had added

```
 { provide: StorageBucket, useValue: 'bucket' }
```

To my providers: on my app.module. I think it was a place holder for something and I forgot to remove it before committing the project.

This led me down and interesting troubleshooting path that finally led me to doing breakpoints and console logs until I found the issue.

```
   const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);
```

I did a console log of **task**, which gave me a location, that's where I found

```
 bucket: bucket
```

I then added the same console.log to a working project that showed

```
 bucket: whatever.appspot.com
```

and I knew I made a mistake somewhere. I just happened across the entry in the app.module.ts file while trying to recreate the issue in stackblitz. The error is resolved.

Comment: I tried the first part of the solution, removing `{provide: StorageBucket, useValue: 'my-bucket-name'}` from my app.module and it worked

Comment: You know Paco I have no idea why I added that bit of code. If I track down what it was I'll also note it. Do you happen to know how you added it? I don't think that just generates in Angular-cli on its own.