# Firebase cloud storage role

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have created brand new app on the firebase.
When i need to save image on the cloud storage i have got this error code below:

```
 "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."
  }
```

Although i have enabled the storage with this role

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Also i have got the error message

```
 "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."
  }
```

Please how can i fix this error
Thanks

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the Storage part of the Firebase console?

Comment: https://ibb.co/tYtzPWD     https://ibb.co/n10HhgM

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292353/firebase-storage-security-rules-400-error-issue-permission-denied-could-not-ac from a while back. If that doesn't solve the issue for you, can you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting?

Comment: I was checked also the url which you give it to me also the same think, i will try to react support. thank you

Comment: *firebaser here* If this was a project that you created in the past few days, you may have been affected by a bug in our project creation. If so, that problem has been fixed so that new projects won't be affected anymore. To fix your existing project, have a look at the steps here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70060240

Comment: Yes it's fix the error , Thank you