# Can't access Firebase Storage data

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Some years ago, I started a android-studio app based on Firebase.
I used Firebase Storage to store my data.
Today, I want to poursue my work. Unfortunately, It appears that I have no more access to my data :
[image: Storage menu - Firebase]

Pushing 'Correct the problem' button tell me that I must assign an additional IAM role to a service account in this project.

After some research, notably [here for IAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292353/firebase-storage-security-rules-400-error-issue-permission-denied-could-not-ac) & [here to check security rules](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/get-started?hl=fr#allow-all), I updated IAM permissions for me and services account, wihtout sucessing to unlock my database (and I certainly add too much permissions) :
[image: IAM roles]

I added Storage Admin & Cloud Storage for Firebase Admin to all services account.
Today I'm still stuck on this point.

Does anyone have any clues on how to restore my access to this data ?

Comment: To take post screenshots of the Firebase console in English, you can add `?hl=en` or `&hl=en` to the URL of your browser.