# Firebase-admin node.js getDownloadURL permission error on external bucket

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

### Need: `getDownloadURL` on external bucket

We have a Firebase/GCP project and we want to use the [`getDownloadURL` Firebase storage function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#shareable_urls) in Node.js to create a permanent signed URL for an object in a bucket in a different project.

Specifically, we have an asset bucket and we want to generate long-lived (forever) URLs for objects in it, but not make the bucket public otherwise.  The asset bucket serves many projects and we want all those projects to all be able to generate URLs against the asset bucket (without having to do anything exotic).

### Reproduction

In a Firebase function (or anything with application-default credentials running as the default service account):

```
import { Storage, type Bucket, type File } from '@google-cloud/storage'
import { getDownloadURL } from 'firebase-admin/storage'

async function getURL (): Promise<string> {
  const b: Bucket = new Storage().bucket("external-asset-bucket")
  const f: File = b.file("/any-file")
  const url = await getDownloadURL(o) // permission error
  return url
}
```

### Error: Permission Denied

When we run the `getDownloadURL` we get the following error:

> "Error: Permission denied. Please enable Firebase Storage for your bucket by visiting the Storage tab in the Firebase Console and ensure that you have sufficient permission to properly provision resources."

The error suggests that we add the bucket to the Firebase project.  When we attempt to add a bucket via the Firebase Console we can create or import a bucket, but it's not clear what "import" means (copy? move bucket across projects? etc), whether it would work across projects. We can't find any documentation indicating what this does or whether it would help, but it also seems unnecessary/irrelevant to the permissions question (which one would expect to be solved by IAM permissions).

### Attempted fixes

We've also found some suggestions that we've tried:

1. granted Storage Admin to firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com on the bucket
2. [set storage rules to allow-all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70950285/19212) on the Firebase project
3. grant Storage Admin on the bucket to the service account that runs the Firebase function

The error gives no useful indication of how to fix this, there's no apparent documentation on what permissions are needed, and most of the information from Google/etc is outdated or wrong.

### Workaround

As a workaround we've also considered using [long-lived V2 Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls-v2) but the documentation specifically says to keep it short-lived, and V4 Signed URLs have an arbitrary 7-day limit, but the `getDownloadURL` function would appear to be the correct/ideal thing to do here (if it worked).

How can we use `getDownloadURL` on an object in a bucket outside the GCP project?

Related:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#shareable_urls
- https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/guide-to-firebase-storage-download-urls-tokens
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1352
- [Get Download URL from file uploaded with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956250)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76744881/19212

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to reproduce the results using the instructions you provide.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson-- trivial repro included.

Answer (score 1):

> When we attempt to add a bucket via the Firebase Console we can create or import a bucket, but it's not clear what "import" means (copy? move bucket across projects? etc), whether it would work across projects. We can't find any documentation indicating what this does or whether it would help

While there is no formal product documentation, the references you're looking for are:

- Launch blog: https://firebase.blog/posts/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage/
  (See the section "Link existing buckets to your projects")
- API method to do this programmatically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/storage/rest/v1beta/projects.buckets/addFirebase

The other bucket must be in the same project as you're using to initialize the Firebase SDK.  If you want to use a bucket in another project, you will need to add Firebase to that other project (aka "import" a GCP project when creating a project in the Fireabse console), then initialize firebase-admin with a service account from that project.

The suggestions that follows assumes that the other bucket is in the same project.

In the console, you can link a bucket to Firebase like this:

1. Go to the Storage product
2. Use the three dot menu on your existing default bucket
3. Choose "Add bucket" option
4. Select "Import existing Google Cloud Storage buckets"

What this does is make the bucket accessible using Firebase APIs and makes the objects subject to security rules on that bucket when accessed from web and mobile clients.

It's unclear if you need to do anything with IAM. My guess is that the default service account should be able to work with all the added buckets.

You might also want to try:

- Using Firebase Admin's [getStorage()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.storage.md#getstorage) to get a Storage reference instead of creating one directly from the GCP API.
- Initializing a separate app using [initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin#initializeapp) with configuration for the bucket you want to use (instead of taking all the defaults) then use `getStorage(app)` to access it.

If you've added a bucket and are not able to work with it using Firebase APIs, you should [reach out to Firebase support directly](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: Thanks Doug, no luck though  We cannot seem to import existing buckets from other projects, so that doesn't work.  Using the Firebase Admin API seems to make no difference.

Comment: It has to be in the same project. I don't think that what you're trying to do is possible without adding Firebase to the other project and using it with the project's own configuration.  Feel free to reach out to Firebase support to explain your use case.  Maybe something can be improved, but you won't get that improvement from volunteers on SO.

Comment: Thanks Doug, appreciate the confirmation.  That cross-project restriction has a significant impact on the use cases, so probably worth noting in the docs.   I've reached out to GCP via our support plan.

Comment: The Firebase documentation generally assumes a level of complexity that's scoped to a single project.  It would require lots of notes across all of the Firebase products to explain that cross-project access is either extremely difficult or impossible.  But please do send your feedback to support.

Comment: In addition to updating the docs, it would also be valuable if the error wasn't vague or misleading.  These assumptions don't seem to be noted anywhere so Firebase consumers must waffle into the ether in the at-best aspirational but routinely-doomed time sink of searching for answers that do not exist.

Comment: Again, great feedback for Firebase.  I can't deliver that any more effectively then you can.

Comment: If you edit the answer to lead with "getDownloadURL from buckets in another project are not currently possible" I'll mark this answer as correct, for the next reader. If GCP support gives a different answer I'll note here and we can revise.