# Error 400 "Bad Request. Could not access bucket" when uploading file to Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a file to Firebase storage using the web API, but the server return this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request. Could not access bucket XXXX.appspot.com"
  }
}
```

I have so far:

- checked the permissions in the Cloud console (see
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50298931/990193 )
- checked that the APIs
  are enabled in the developers console (see the comments in
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334122/990193 )
- configured for CORS (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?authuser=0#cors_configuration )

BTW downloading file works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was calling the `put` method on my storage ref with a non valid path. With a proper file path it works.

Very misleading error message from firebase nevertheless...

Comment: Just wanted to say, I had a `Bad Request` because I tried to send a file as multipart in guzzle php, but that was wrong (for whatever reason). So even if the error is vague, it points in the right direction.